# How to run dictionary over file

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I have got dataset like that

| RespID | AGE | GEO | GEN | PROD | BRND | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 1 | 6 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 9 |
| 3 | 4 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 6 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 7 | 4 | 3 |
| 5 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 3 |
| 6 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 2 |
| 7 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 7 | 2 | 10 |
| 8 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 6 |
| 9 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 3 | 9 |
| 10 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 7 | 7 | 7 |

and for each dataset I'll be provided with another file, constructed in the way it is on the capture

[image]

The question is: is there a possibility to somehow create a dictionary or something else out of the file which is in the capture and then run over the table so I dont have geo = 1 but Ryga or Other and so on? I'll be also provided with 1-10 for Q1-Q3(not available as for now). I only know how to change name of the columns using dictionary but not really the values, dynamically. Will be using databricks so python and pyspark is available

Thank you very much for help and tips

Comment: Would a solution with pandas be of any help for you?

Comment: Not really, we tend to not run pandas in production. Anyway thanks for your reply. I am pretty close to solve it myself but of course it requires a bit better input with descriptions

Comment: Sure. Good luck then!

Answer (score 0):

Create a [case statement](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.5.0/api/sql/index.html#case) for each column that should be translated.

Here an example for the two columns `GEN` and `GEO`:

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = <input data>

translations = [
    ('GEN', {1: 'Female', 2: 'Male'}),
    ('GEO', {1: 'Ryga', 2: 'Others'})
]

df1 = df
for translation in translations:
    stmt = f'case {translation[0]}'
    for (k,v) in translation[1].items():
      stmt = stmt + f' when {k} then "{v}"'
    stmt = stmt + ' end'
    df1 = df1.withColumn(translation[0], F.expr(stmt))

df1.show()
```

Output:

```
+------+---+------+------+----+----+---+---+---+
|RespID|AGE|   GEO|   GEN|PROD|BRND| Q1| Q2| Q3|
+------+---+------+------+----+----+---+---+---+
|     1|  1|  Ryga|Female|   3|   3|  4|  1|  6|
|     2|  1|Others|  Male|   2|   1|  1|  4|  9|
|     3|  4|Others|  Male|   1|   1|  3|  4|  6|
|     4|  1|  Ryga|  Male|   3|   2|  7|  4|  3|
|     5|  2|  Ryga|Female|   3|   2|  1|  4|  3|
|     6|  1|  Ryga|  Male|   2|   3|  2|  4|  2|
|     7|  2|Others|  Male|   3|   3|  7|  2| 10|
|     8|  4|Others|Female|   1|   1|  4|  2|  6|
|     9|  3|  Ryga|  Male|   2|   2|  4|  3|  9|
|    10|  1|Others|Female|   1|   1|  7|  7|  7|
+------+---+------+------+----+----+---+---+---+
```

The list of translations can be extended for the other columns as required.